# How can I set a user-defined field?

Tags: acumatica

I have added a user defined checkbox UsrContractCustomer to CRCase. My first step is to try to set the checkbox when the user selects the Business Account (CustomerID).

[image: Contract Customer Checkbox]

Here is my latest attempt to set the checkbox.

```
  protected void CRCase_CustomerID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
    var row = (CRCase)e.Row;
    if (row.CustomerID != null)
    {
      //CRCaseExt rowExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row);
      CRCaseExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>();
      rowExt.UsrContractCustomer = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your field in your dac extension you should be able to use a formula to set the value. This will check or uncheck you field when the customer is entered or removed. Having the logic on the field also removes the need to write graph level changes such as events.

```
[PXFormula(typeof(IIf<Where<CRCase.customerID, IsNull>, False, True>))]
```

If you want to use the event as you have it I would try cache set value such as:

```
cache.SetValueExt<CRCaseExt.usrContractCustomer>(e.Row, row.CustomerID != null);
```

Comment: Thank you Brendan.  For right now I am going to stick with the event approach.  My next step is to determine whether the selected customer has an active contract and then set the checkbox if that is true.  I that something I could do in the DAC?

Comment: If you can write the BQL statement yes you can use that statement within PXFormula. When no customer the bql should not return the value so false will be set (same as my answer). Using the event... did SetValueExt work?

Answer (score 0):

Brendan's solution is correct.  In another post I retrieved the value that I wanted to use to set the user-defined field. The 'false' was replaced with a condition that sets the checkbox field.

```
sender.SetValueExt<CRCaseExt.usrContractCustomer>(crcase, false);
```

Thanks for the help and support.